# NuGet.Config is malformed, Please check NuGet.Config - solution

Tags: nuget, config

After installing Update1 for VS 2015 I had a problem when trying to add local path for Nuget Manager. 
Message was:
"NuGet.Config is malformed, Please check NuGet.Config"

In my case it was enough to find a nuget.config in path:
C:\Users\_my_user_name_\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\

Nuget.config file was empty (but size was 1KB). 
I just filled it with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
</configuration>
```

And problem in VS didn't appear again.

Comment: I had the same issue and adding in a default Nuget.Config worked for me although I had to restart VS before it was recognised.

Comment: Same issue here, 1KB of spaces.  Removed it and put in your three lines.  Fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, %appdata%\nuget\nuget.config existed and was populated,... but its xml header claimed utf-8 when the file was really encoded fully-Unicode.  Saving as utf-8 bom got me going again.